# A better database plugin for Netbeans, other than the standard one

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, netbeans, ide

Netbeans has a database plugin, which you can add columns or tables, but it doesn't have options for mysql, such as autoincrement or foreign key management for innodb.

Is there any alternatives to the database plugin?

It seems like netbeans has some database diagram editor somewhere and keeping it to the enterprise edition. I am developing php applications using netbeans and I have other database management applications for mysql but I find it practical to have a database manager in the IDE.

Do you know about any database plugins which is not listed in the plugins directory?

I am willing to try anything.